# Need some help with the use of matlab to approximate a singular integral

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, matlab, singular-integrals

I want to write an essay about one method that matlab uses to compute an approximation of integrals which include singularities as in:

$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin (x^{5})}{x^{2}(1+x)^{55}}dx$

However after much research I haven't gotten much further due to the vast amount of different methods that can be used to approximate such an integral. I was hoping that one of you might know a method that can solve such integrals with a relatively high precision and is that is appropriate/interesting enough to write an essay on.

Regards,

Lorenzo

Comment: I would go for a change of variable followed by a Laplace transform/ an application of the residue theorem. For instance, the Laplace transform turns the oscillating integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x+2\pi}\,dx$ into $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-2\pi s}}{1+s^2}\,ds$ that is way more manageable.